# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1 when connection to anything on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, http

I try to connect from a node.js backend to a different server running on localhost. Every server is running in a docker container.  When I execute the http request I receive 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80' or 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4200' when connection to anything on localhost. My code looks the following:

```
const http = require('http');

const xy = http.get('http://localhost/path', (r) =>{
  console.log(r);
});
xy.on('error', e => {
  console.log(e);
});

const xz = http.get('http://localhost:4200', (r) =>{
  console.log(r);
});
xz.on('error', e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

I do not understand, why it does not work. The same request in the browser does work. Connecting to different URLs like google.com does also work. Here is the output of netstat -na:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4200            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localhost` inside a container refers to the container itself, not your laptop/server. So the other service is not running there.

If you want to connect from a container to another container you should use the name of the container instead localhost.

Also, containers need to be inside the same [network](https://docs.docker.com/network/)